# MIN() y MAX() para establecer hora de entrada y salida de trabajo de un empleado

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

Mi problema se plantea de esta manera: Tengo una tabla con todas las marcaciones de los empleados, estas poseen los parámetros de userid y checktime (incluye fecha y hora), todos estos datos se almacenan en forma de lista.

Ejemplo:

```
userid      checktime
1           2021-04-30 19:25:27.000
1           2021-05-03 09:05:29.000
2           2021-05-03 12:59:34.000
2           2021-05-03 12:59:35.000
3           2021-05-03 13:00:01.000
3           2021-05-03 14:28:12.000
[...]
```

Mi objetivo es tomar las marcaciones de la hora de entrada de trabajo y hora de salida del trabajo de forma lineal por cada empleo por fecha. Y en caso de que no haya registro de hora de salida (ya sea porque el empleado se olvido marcar su salida), mostrar el campo como 00:00:00 o null

ejemplo:

```
userid     fecha        entrada     salida
---------------------------------------------
1          2021/04/30   19:25:27    00:00:00
2          2021/05/03   07:30:00    18:00:00
3          2021/05/04   07:30:00    18:00:00
4          2021/05/05   07:30:00    18:00:00
5          2021/05/06   09:30:00    00:00:00
```

La manera en como lo hice es la siguiente:

```
SELECT USERID,CHECKTIME, MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CHECKTIME, 108)) 'MIN', MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CHECKTIME, 108)) 'MAX' FROM dbo.marcaciones GROUP BY USERID, CHECKTIME ORDER BY USERID;
```

Y no he podido lograrlo. ¿Me pueden ayudar?

Comment: Si quieres agrupar por día, tienes que incluir solamente la parte fecha de `CHECKTIME` en el GROUP BY, por ejemplo `GROUP BY USERID, CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE)`

Comment: ¿Siempre los empleados entran y salen en el día o pueden entrar un día y salir en el otro (turnos nocturnos)? ¿Hay algún otro atributo que determine si se trata de una entrada o una salida?

Comment: El horario es matutino, el único campo que almacena la hora y fecha de ingreso es CHECKTIME. Entonces cada vez que el empleado registra su entrada, se guarda en la base de datos. La mayoria de veces, los empleados registran su entrada 2 veces y 2 veces van a la base de datos, y es ahi el problema

Answer (score 2):

Para que te agrupe por día, debes tomar solamente la parte de la fecha de `CHECKTIME` para el `GROUP BY`.

En cuanto a ponerla como `NULL` u otra cosa cuando no haya fecha, depende de lo que haya en ese caso. Suponiendo que habría una cadena vacía, esto haría el trabajo. Dependiendo de tu contexto puede que sean necesarias varias comprobaciones. Esto sería muy fácil con `TRY_CONVERT` pero está disponible a partir de SQL Server 2012.

```
SELECT 
    USERID,
    CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE), 
    MIN(CASE WHEN CHECKTIME="" THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(8), CHECKTIME, 108)) 'MIN', 
    MAX(CASE WHEN CHECKTIME="" THEN NULL ELSE CONVERT(CHAR(8), CHECKTIME, 108)) 'MAX' 
FROM dbo.marcaciones 
    GROUP BY USERID, CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE) 
    ORDER BY USERID;
```

Comment: Gracias, pero aun no me funciona

Comment: @CesarHR ¿qué resultados arroja la consulta propuesta?

Comment: en el `select` también debes usar `CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE)`

Comment: Es cierto, colocando el CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE ) en el select ha funcionado! Muchas gracias. Antes no lo habia hecho así como la sugerencia del compañero y me mandaba error y por eso lo borraba.

Comment: Cierto, se me escapó. Gracias @PatricioMoracho.

Answer (score 2):

En primer lugar, por tu comentario, obviaremos los casos de horarios nocturnos que requieren otro tipo de solución algo más compleja, aún así hay algunos problemas que no tienen una solución clara:

1. Un solo registro en el día ¿es una entrada o una salida?
2. Únicamente 2 registros consecutivos, segundos de diferencia para entrada o para salida

Primero obtenemos el valor mínimo y máximo por usuario y fecha:

```
SELECT USERID,
       CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE) as Fecha, 
       MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CHECKTIME, 108)) as 'entrada', 
       MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CHECKTIME, 108)) as 'salida',
       FROM dbo.marcaciones 
       GROUP BY USERID, CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE)
```

En una subconsulta intentaremos resolver las cuestiones anteriores

```
SELECT T.USERID,
       T.Fecha,
       T.entrada,
       CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(ss, T.salida, T.entrada) <= 5 THEN NULL ELSE T.salida END as 'salida'
       FROM (SELECT USERID,
                    CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE) as Fecha, 
                    MIN(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CHECKTIME, 108)) as 'entrada', 
                    MAX(CONVERT(CHAR(8), CHECKTIME, 108)) as 'salida',
                    FROM dbo.marcaciones 
                    GROUP BY USERID, CAST(CHECKTIME AS DATE)
       ) T
       ORDER BY T.USERID, T.Fecha
```

Finalmente con esto conseguimos que: 1) Un solo registro en el día se considera que es una entrada (eventualmente se podría ver si es mayor a cierta hora para considerarlo una salida) 2) Si hay únicamente dos registros consecutivos de hasta 5 segundos de diferencia, o un único registro, se considera solo como entrada y la salida será NULL.

Esto es apenas básico, el manejo de horarios es un tema complejo, por ejemplo este esquema no te permite por ejemplo determinar ausencias (días sin registro)